# Smart group selecting more contacts than match criteria

Tags: smartgroups

I've tried to test v4.7.13 smart groups with relative dates after the bug is supposedly fixed:
[Is it a bug that Relative Dates are broken in Search and Smart Groups?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/is-it-a-bug-that-relative-dates-are-broken-in-search-and-smart-groups)

1. Now, I create an Activity today for one contact.
2. I do advanced search for contacts with Activity = Today.
3. Search gives me the one contact with Activity = Today.
4. I create smart group out of that search.
5. I go to Contacts > Manage groups and see that in my group is 1156 contacts (from which only one match criteria, namely, has Activity = Today).

**UPDATE:**
Bug is replicated in CiviCRM Drupal Sandbox v4.7.14.
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/group/search?force=1&context=smog&gid=7&qfKey=59a9c20b96f05a8c46befb01c385c298_1338

(Or see group **Activity Today** in Contacts > Manage Groups)

Comment: are you going to feedback on JIRA?

Comment: I am not very experienced with this, but I just did.
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19631

Comment: cool though from a quick look i wonder if these are all related? 19394, 19250 19625 19631